# How to make sorting key insensitive in ag-grid?

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I am working in some grids and I notice that the sorting on all of them is key sensitive is there any way to change that. This is a part of my code.

```
 columnDefs = [
{
  headerName: 'Id', field: 'id', sort: 'asc', sortable: true, filter: true,
  checkboxSelection: true, resizable: true,
},
{
  headerName: 'Name', field: 'name', sortable: true, filter: true,
  checkboxSelection: false, editable: true, resizable: true,
},
{
  headerName: 'Description', field: 'description', sortable: true, filter: true,
  checkboxSelection: false, editable: true, resizable: true,
},
  ];
```

Thank you for any possible given help.

This is how i have implement the solution by ##wentjun##:

```
  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog, private adminService: AdminService) {}

  columnDefs = [
    {
      headerName: 'Id', field: 'id', sortable: true, filter: true,
      checkboxSelection: true, resizable: true,
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Name', field: 'name', sortable: true, filter: true,
      checkboxSelection: false, editable: true, resizable: true,
      comparator: this.customComparator,
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Description',  field: 'description', sortable: true, filter: true,
      checkboxSelection: false, editable: true, resizable: true,
    },
  ];

  customComparator(valueA, valueB) {
    return valueA.toLowerCase().localeCompare(valueB.toLowerCase());
  }
```

Comment: Please take a look here: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/9205

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This can be done by using a [custom sorting function](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-sorting/#example-custom-sorting) on the particular column that requires case-insensitive sorting.

For instance, for your `columnDefs`, if you require the `name` column to be sorted case insentitve, we pass the `customComparator` as the value for the `comparator` property. In your ngOnInit,

```
this.columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: 'Name',
    field: 'name',
    sort: 'asc',  // optional, allows grid column to be sorted on init
    comparator: customComparator
  },
  // other columns
];
```

Then, we define the customComparator such that it carries out case-insentitive sorting. We do so by converting the values to lowercase on the custom comparator.

```
const customComparator = (valueA, valueB) => {
  return valueA.toLowerCase().localeCompare(valueB.toLowerCase());
};
```

---

EDIT: I have forked and recreated a [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/0S6ssQNfoQ3pD6cn9wQR?p=preview) from the original ag-grid demo to demonstrate the usage of the above comparator. Refer to the constructor() method for the relevant details.

Comment: Hello can you please do a stackblitz cause I am not having the result I want.
if i want
A
a
b
C and so on

Comment: @IliaTapia Ok, here you go: https://plnkr.co/edit/0S6ssQNfoQ3pD6cn9wQR?p=preview . It is quite messy, as I forked it from the original demo, but I have included the necessary code at `app.component.ts`, under the `constructor()`. Refer to the first column of `columnDefs`, with the header field called `athlete`. You can try commenting and uncommenting the line with the `comparator` property to test that it works.

Comment: I can't use like you did, but I am using directly like a function and not a const and seems not to work, am i missing sth or what am i doing wrong

Comment: @IliaTapia Could you please show a snippet of your code? Technically speaking, mine is an anonymous function.

Comment: I accept your answer please if you don't mind to upvote my post so I can have the opportunity to do more question in the future

Comment: @IliaTapia Sure, definitely. Good luck!!

Comment: Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57528061/inconsistent-alphanumeric-sorting-with-ag-grid-and-string-cells?noredirect=1#comment101532009_57528061 I recommend adding a `.trim()` to each string in a custom comparator for strings, as in many cases you may not have full control over the quality of your data, and you don't want to pull your hair out (like I did) trying to find out why the sorting is inconsistent.

Comment: Here is the comparator expression that worked best for me: `valueA.trim().charAt(0).toLowerCase().localeCompare(valueB.trim().charAt(0).toLowerCase());`

This takes into account trailing spaces, and also sorts by just the first character of the string.  I was getting odd results if there were special characters anywhere in the string.

Comment: Oh my God... it's 2020, agGrid is bang up-to-date, yet we're still having to write our own sort functions to compare strings properly....  I thought these days were behind us....!!

Comment: @MikeGledhill agreed. This could have been encapsulated as built-in sorting option, rather than having developers rewriting the same thing all over again :)

Answer (score 6):

Note that by now you can just set the `accentedSort` property in the `GridOptions` to `true` to achieve case-insensitive sorting. [See here for more information](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-sorting/#accented-sort).

If you use the custom comparator solution from wentjun please make sure to only apply it to string columns or, when applying to all columns, check if the value is a string. Otherwise the sorting won't work anymore on number based columns:

```
const customLowerCaseComparator = (valueA, valueB) => {
  if (typeof valueA === 'string') {
    return valueA.toLowerCase().localeCompare(valueB.toLowerCase());
  }

  return (valueA > valueB? 1 : (valueA < valueB ? -1 : 0));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Update for 2020-07, `agTextColumnFilter` that is the default ag-Grid filter, accepts parameters. One of which is `caseSensitive`.
[See sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYByW.png)

Comment: This works for the text filter. It does not seem to impact the sorting, however.