# Ag-grid sorting doesn't work properly for am pm times

Tags: javascript, angular, date, frontend, ag-grid

I need to be able to show a list of schedules by ascendent or descendent order. Ag-grid does this by default, but after the manipulation of my data to show the times in AM PM format, the order is the contrary of what is desirable (like, in ascendent order, 01:00 PM shows before 10:00 AM).

How could I make the sorting order by the raw data, not the data shown in the table?

Comment: Can you show us your code?Or better still,  you can create a demo on stackblitz or codesandbox? Generally, you will need to write a custom sorting function such as this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56273293/10959940

Comment: I created a comparator for the values using Data.parse() and it worked for what I needed. Thanks for your answer @wentjun

Comment: You added a comment @wentjun not an answer, I'm not sure I can upvote :(

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved using **custom comparator** and if you dont want to write your own comparator.

you can configure this by setting the property

```
gridOptions.accentedSort = true
```

Because by default sorting doesn't take into consideration locale-specific characters. If you need to make your sort **locale-specific**
Using this feature can be expensive if you need to sort a very large amount of data.